# TFS Release definition - Application pool is not getting created with the custom account details

Tags: powershell, tfs, release, release-management

I'm trying to create a release definition to create an application pool when deploying a new application. The new application pool is getting created with the new application name.

But, i want it to be created under a custom service account. Where it is getting created with ApplicationPoolIdentity.

PFB the powershell script i'm using to create the application and its app-pool as one of the tasks in the release definition,

```
-serverName $(Release.EnvironmentName) 
    -userName $(AdminLogin) 
    -password $(Password) 
    -webApplicationName RexxOnlineUpdateProcessing.Service 
    -webSiteName 'Default Web Site' 
    -appPool RexxOnlineUpdateProcessing.Service 
    -appPoolIdentity 4 
    -appPoolUserName $(AppPoolIdentityUserName) 
    -appPoolPassword $(AppPoolIdentityPassword) 
    -websiteBindingProtocols 'http/*:80:'
```

Please let me know if i'm missing something here.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How did you specify your release definition?

Answer (score 0):

The identityType's value should be 3 for a custom account. Check [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel#configuration).

By the way, you could use [WinRM - IIS Web App Management](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppMgmt/README_IISAppMgmt.md) task to create application pool. In this task, you could choose `Custom Account` Identity, once custom account is selected, then username and password will show up:

[image]